# How to get dictionary values having its keys as a list

Tags: python

With dictionary:

```
dictionary={1:'One', 2:'Two', 3:'Three', 4:'Four', 5:'Five'}
```

and a list of known keys:

```
keys=[2, 4]
```

What is the fastest shortest way to retrieve dictionary values?

The goal is to replace this code:

```
result=[]
for key in dictionary:
    if not key in keys: continue
    result.append(dictionary[key])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use list expression checking key existence

```
result=[dictionary[k] for k in keys if k in dictionary]
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a list comprehension:

```
[dictionary[k] for k in keys]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
print [dictionary[k] for k in dictionary.keys() if k in keys]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
dictionary={1:'One', 2:'Two', 3:'Three', 4:'Four', 5:'Five'}
result = [dictionary[i] for i in dictionary.keys()]
print result

Output:
['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five']
```

Comment: This print all values, Is there any difference with a simple dictionary.values()? What about knonw keys array?

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED** you can use this

```
   result = map(lambda x:x[1],dictionary.items())
```

Example

```
   dictionary = {'x': 1, 'y': 2, 'z': 3} 
   dictionary.items()
   >>[('y', 2), ('x', 1), ('z', 3)]

   result = map(lambda x:x[1],dictionary.items())
   print result 
   >>[2, 1, 3]
```

Comment: This is an inefficient implementation of `dictionary.values()` that does not limit the results to those for a known list of keys, as the OP requested.